# UInavigation button style

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisplitview, uinavigationcontroller

Im working on a UINavigation controller on the iphone...when u click it it pushes a new view...Exactly like your settings on the iphone.

The problem is...althought i have done this i cant make it look exactly like the settings of the iphone has it
example they have a picture and a nice little arrow.

If this is custom id love if someone had a link to do it...thank you

Link to what im reffering too if i didnt explain it properly
http://cdn.kevinworthington.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/iPhone-settings1.png

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this library will help you

http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

Comment: Thank you, does look like what im trying to accomplish